# Display Sensor Data to Web

Tags: python, javascript, beginner, html, python-2.x

Last time [I worked on a DHT11 sensor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/156400/reading-a-dht11-to-a-file) and got a lot of feedback, this time I have added another sensor (the BMP180), stored both of them in MySQL, and am now displaying them to the web.

The Raspberry Pi now has an HTTP server running on port 80, and I've built a small little UI to display all my sensor data.

[image: Graphs and UI]

So this is all provided by a few files, one of them is a JavaScript file, one is a CSS file, one is an HTML file, and the rest are python files.

We'll start with the JavaScript for the graphs. This is pretty simple and self explanatory, the biggest issue I have is I need to break this down further so that there's no duplication. This is `graphs.js`:

```js
function buildGraph(svgTitle, table, title) {
    var svg = d3.select(svgTitle);
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        //.curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Logged); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });

    var area = d3.area()
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        //.curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Logged); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });

    d3.tsv("history.py?LogType=" + table, function(d) {
        d.Logged = parseTime(d.Logged);
        d.Value = +d.Value;
        return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Logged; }));
        var yS = y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Value; })).nice();

        area.y0(y(yS.domain()[0]));

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-height));

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(-width))
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "#000")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "em")
            .text(title);

        g.select(".y")
            .select(".domain")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-1,0)");

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("fill-opacity", "0.3")
            .attr("stroke", "none")
            .attr("d", area);
    });
}

function updateGraph(svgTitle, table, title) {
    var svg = d3.select(svgTitle);
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
    var width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right;
    var height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var g = svg.select("g");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var line = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        //.curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Logged); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });

    var area = d3.area()
        .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
        //.curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.Logged); })
        .y1(function(d) { return y(d.Value); });

    d3.tsv("history.py?LogType=" + table, function(d) {
        d.Logged = parseTime(d.Logged);
        d.Value = +d.Value;
        return d;
    }, function(error, data) {
        if (error) throw error;

        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Logged; }));
        var yS = y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Value; })).nice();

        area.y0(y(yS.domain()[0]));

        g.selectAll("path").remove();
        g.selectAll("g").remove();

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-height));

        g.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(-width))
            .append("text")
            .attr("fill", "#000")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
            .attr("y", 6)
            .attr("dy", "0.71em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "em")
            .text(title);

        g.select(".y")
            .select(".domain")
            .attr("transform", "translate(-1,0)");

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
            .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
            .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
            .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
            .attr("d", line);

        g.append("path")
            .datum(data)
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .attr("fill-opacity", "0.3")
            .attr("stroke", "none")
            .attr("d", area);
    });
}
```

Next we have the `index.html` page, which is not actually loaded by the browser. It's the template for the `index.py` to load, though it doesn't have to be now. (Previously I was doing wonky things with it.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        <link href='bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src='d3/d3.min.js'></script>
        <script src='graphs.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Last refresh: <span class="lastRefresh"></span>;
        Pi time: <span class="piTime"></span>;
        Next sensor pull: <span class="nextRefresh"></span> (<span class="nextRefreshSeconds"></span>)
    </div>
    <div class="current">
        Most recent readings (<span id="logValue"></span>):
        <span class="">
            Temp 1:
            <span id="temperatureValue"></span>F
        </span>
        <span class="">
            Humidity:
            <span id="humidityValue"></span>%
        </span>
        <span class="">
            Pressure:
            <span id="pressureValue"></span>inhg
        </span>
        <span class="">
            Temp 2:
            <span id="bmpTempValue"></span>F
        </span>
        <span class="">
            Altitude:
            <span id="altitudeValue"></span>ft
        </span>
        <span class="">
            Sea Level Pressure:
            <span id="seaPressureValue"></span>inhg
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class='graphBlock'>
        <svg class='temp' width='1260' height='240'></svg>
        <svg class='humid' width='1260' height='240'></svg>
        <svg class='pressure' width='1260' height='240'></svg>
        <svg class='bmpTemp' width='1260' height='240'></svg>
        <svg class='altitude' width='1260' height='240'></svg>
        <svg class='seaPressure' width='1260' height='240'></svg>
    </div>
    <script src='jquery.1.12.4.min.js'></script>
    <script src='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base, chr) {
            var len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length) + 1;
            return len > 0 ? new Array(len).join(chr || '0') + this : this;
        }

        function round(value, decimals) {
            return Number(Math.round(value + 'e' + decimals) + 'e-' + decimals);
        }

        function updateGraphs(callback) {
            if (callback == null) {
                callback = updateGraph;
            }

            callback('.temp', 'Temperature', 'Temp (F)');
            callback('.humid', 'Humidity', 'Humidity (%)');
            callback('.pressure', 'Pressure', 'Pressure (inhg)');
            callback('.bmpTemp', 'BmpTemp', 'Temp (F)');
            callback('.altitude', 'Altitude', 'Altitude (ft)');
            callback('.seaPressure', 'SeaPressure', 'Sea Level Pressure (inhg)');

            var d = new Date;
            var dFormat = [d.getUTCFullYear(), (d.getUTCMonth() + 1).padLeft(), d.getUTCDate().padLeft()].join('-');
            dFormat += " ";
            dFormat += [d.getUTCHours().padLeft(), d.getUTCMinutes().padLeft(), d.getUTCSeconds().padLeft()].join(':');
            $('.lastRefresh').html(dFormat);
        }

        function updateTimes() {
            updatePiTime();
        }

        function updatePiTime(target, params) {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    var text = xmlHttp.responseText.trim().split("\n");
                    $(".nextRefresh").html(text[0]);
                    $(".nextRefreshSeconds").html(text[1]);
                    $(".piTime").html(text[2]);
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "time.py?All=true", true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

        function updateCurrents() {
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                    var text = xmlHttp.responseText.trim().split("\n");
                    text.forEach(function(line) {
                        var items = line.split("\t");
                        switch (items[0]) {
                            case "Humidity":
                                $("#humidityValue").html(round(items[2], 2));
                                break;
                            case "BmpTemp":
                                $("#bmpTempValue").html(round(items[2], 2));
                                break;
                            case "Pressure":
                                $("#pressureValue").html(round(items[2], 2));
                                break;
                            case "Altitude":
                                $("#altitudeValue").html(round(items[2], 2));
                                break;
                            case "Temperature":
                                $("#temperatureValue").html(round(items[2], 2));
                                break;
                            case "SeaPressure":
                                $("#seaPressureValue").html(round(items[2], 2));
                                break;
                        }
                        $("#logValue").html(items[1]);
                    });
                }
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", "latest.py", true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

        updateGraphs(buildGraph);
        updateTimes();
        updateCurrents();
        setInterval(updateGraphs, 5000);
        setInterval(updateTimes, 500);
        setInterval(updateCurrents, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the root of the web page is JavaScript, that's to keep data updated so that page refreshes aren't required.

All the CSS code, which is pretty simple (`style.css`):

```
body {
    background: #202020;
    color: #efefef;
}

svg {
    display: inline-block;
}

.graphBlock {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.axis line {
    stroke: #303030;
}

.axis.y path,
.axis.y .tick:nth-child(2) line {
    stroke: #efefef;
}

.axis path {
    stroke: #303030;
}

.axis text {
    fill: #efefef;
}

.header {
    /*color: #efefef;*/
    background: #07507F;
    padding: 5px;
}

.current {
    /*color: #efefef;*/
    background: #07507F;
    padding: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #303030;
}
```

Then we have `index.py`, the main landing page:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql

# Now we do the rest of the work
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Print the header first, always
    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print

    with open("index.html") as template:
        print template.read()
```

Then we have the asynchronously requested python scripts. The first is `time.py` since it's the shortest:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import cgi


DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-Type: text/html"
    print

    args = cgi.FieldStorage()
    date_format = DEFAULT_DATE_FORMAT
    if "DateFormat" in args:
        date_format = args["DateFormat"].value

    if "Next" in args or "All" in args:
        utctime = datetime.utcnow()
        print (utctime + timedelta(seconds = 60 - utctime.second)).strftime(date_format)
    if "NextIn" in args or "All" in args:
        utctime = datetime.utcnow()
        print str(60 - utctime.second) + " seconds"
    if (not "Next" in args and not "NextIn" in args) or "All" in args:
        print datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format)
```

You can probably guess that it's only job is to return each time operation.

Next we have `latest.py`, which returns the latest value of each metric:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import cgi
import pymysql


DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT = 7
DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print

    args = cgi.FieldStorage()
    start_date = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days = DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT)).strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    end_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    minute_group = DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING
    gather = []

    gather.append(("HumidityLog", lambda x: x))
    gather.append(("BmpTempLog", lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32))
    gather.append(("PressureLog", lambda p: p * 0.0002953))
    gather.append(("AltitudeLog", lambda m: m * 3.28084))
    gather.append(("TemperatureLog", lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32))
    gather.append(("SeaPressureLog", lambda p: p * 0.0002953))

    if "Start" in args:
        start_date = args["Start"].value
    if "End" in args:
        end_date = args["End"].value

    conn = pymysql.connect(
        db='WeatherLog',
        user='WeatherLog',
        passwd='Weather!',
        host='localhost')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    for table, formatter in gather:
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT
                Logged, AVG(Value)
            FROM
                {0}
            WHERE
                Logged >= '{1}' AND Logged <= '{2}'
            GROUP BY
                ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Logged)/({3} * 60))
            ORDER BY
                Logged DESC
            LIMIT
                1;""".format(table, start_date, end_date, minute_group))

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print "{2}\t{0}\t{1}".format(row[0], formatter(row[1]), table[:-3])
```

And then finally we have `history.py`, which returns the history for a single metric in tab-delimited format:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import cgi
import pymysql


DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT = 7
DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING = 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print

    args = cgi.FieldStorage()
    start_date = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days = DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT)).strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    end_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    minute_group = DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING
    table = "TemperatureLog"

    formatter = lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32

    if "LogType" in args:
        log_type = args["LogType"].value
        if log_type == "Humidity":
            table = "HumidityLog"
            formatter = lambda x: x
        elif log_type == "BmpTemp":
            table = "BmpTempLog"
            formatter = lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32
        elif log_type == "Pressure":
            table = "PressureLog"
            formatter = lambda p: p * 0.0002953
        elif log_type == "Altitude":
            table = "AltitudeLog"
            formatter = lambda m: m * 3.28084
        elif log_type == "SeaPressure":
            table = "SeaPressureLog"
            formatter = lambda p: p * 0.0002953

    if "Start" in args:
        start_date = args["Start"].value
    if "End" in args:
        end_date = args["End"].value

    conn = pymysql.connect(
        db='WeatherLog',
        user='WeatherLog',
        passwd='Weather!',
        host='localhost')
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT
            Logged, AVG(Value)
        FROM
            {0}
        WHERE
            Logged >= '{1}' AND Logged <= '{2}'
        GROUP BY
            ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Logged)/({3} * 60));""".format(table, start_date, end_date, minute_group))

    didfirst = 0
    print "Logged\tValue"
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        didfirst = 1
        print "{0}\t{1}".format(row[0], formatter(row[1]))
```

Any suggestions, advice and critiques are welcome. This is going to slowly get larger, and I'm going to be significantly increasing what it does so I want to get the structure and design setup correctly initially.

Comment: Those temperature readings look glitchy.

Comment: @200_success I have a loose ground on the sensor, I haven't yet soldered anything together, so sometimes the ground breaks and the reading is messed up.

Comment: @EBrown there is also the ["Home Assistant"](https://home-assistant.io/) project - looks relevant to the things you are working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’ve got at least two bits of somehow duplicated code in your Python files. Better build a utility module to reduce that.

**utils.py**

```
import pymysql


METRICS_FORMATTERS = {
    "HumidityLog": lambda x: x,
    "BmpTempLog": lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32,
    "PressureLog": lambda p: p * 0.0002953,
    "AltitudeLog": lambda m: m * 3.28084,
    "TemperatureLog": lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32,
    "SeaPressureLog": lambda p: p * 0.0002953,
}


def connect_to_database():
    return pymysql.connect(
        db='WeatherLog',
        user='WeatherLog',
        passwd='Weather!',
        host='localhost')
```

You can then simplify your scripts:

**latest.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import cgi
import utils


DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT = 7
DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print

    args = cgi.FieldStorage()
    start_date = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT)).strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    end_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    minute_group = DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING

    if "Start" in args:
        start_date = args["Start"].value
    if "End" in args:
        end_date = args["End"].value

    conn = utils.connect_to_database()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    for table, formatter in utils.METRICS_FORMATTERS.iteritems():
        cursor.execute("""
            SELECT
                Logged, AVG(Value)
            FROM
                {0}
            WHERE
                Logged >= '{1}' AND Logged <= '{2}'
            GROUP BY
                ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Logged)/({3} * 60))
            ORDER BY
                Logged DESC
            LIMIT
                1;""".format(table, start_date, end_date, minute_group))

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print "{2}\t{0}\t{1}".format(row[0], formatter(row[1]), table[:-3])
```

**history.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

import cgi
import utils


DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT = 7
DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING = 3


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Content-type: text/html"
    print

    args = cgi.FieldStorage()
    start_date = (datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days = DEFAULT_DAY_LIMIT)).strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    end_date = datetime.utcnow().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
    minute_group = DEFAULT_MINUTE_GROUPING

    table = "TemperatureLog"
    formatter = lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32

    if "LogType" in args:
        log_type = args["LogType"].value + "Log"
        try:
            formatter = utils.METRICS_FORMATTERS[log_type]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            table = log_type

    if "Start" in args:
        start_date = args["Start"].value
    if "End" in args:
        end_date = args["End"].value

    conn = connect_to_database()
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT
            Logged, AVG(Value)
        FROM
            {0}
        WHERE
            Logged >= '{1}' AND Logged <= '{2}'
        GROUP BY
            ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Logged)/({3} * 60));""".format(table, start_date, end_date, minute_group))

    didfirst = 0
    print "Logged\tValue"
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
        didfirst = 1
        print "{0}\t{1}".format(row[0], formatter(row[1]))
```

---

Writting that, I realize that there are even more duplicated code, let's refactor the hell out of it. You need:

- A way to retrieve start and end dates out of the query string or sensible defaults;
- A way to perform a `SELECT` statement;
- A way to format the response (with headers first, always).

Start and end arguments are simple and are done similarly to `connect_to_database()`. Performing the query, though, can benefit from some advices. For starter, and even though the raspberry is on your network with only you accessing it, it always feel bad to see SQL queries with user-provided values injected directly into it. You should take the habit to use [parametrized statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1947993/5069029); [`pymysql` using the `'format'` kind of markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29552745/which-python-mysql-client-libraries-support-named-parameters), you can use:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT Logged, Avg(Value)
    FROM %s
    WHERE Logged >= '%s' AND Logged <= '%s'
    GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Logged)/(%s * 60));
""", (table, start_date, end_date, minute_group))
```

You may optionnaly also use the [connection's context-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31214658/can-i-use-pymysql-connect-with-with-statement) that provides you with a cursor open a transaction and auto commit/rollback it when leaving the block (even though it's not useful on a SELECT statement, it's also a good habit to have).

Also don't forget to `close()` your connection once you’re done with it.

Lastly, formatting the response can be done by providing the formatting function an iterable of the response content. The easiest one to come up with is a list, but it can also be any kind of generator.

All in all, I would write:

**utils.py**

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import cgi

import pymysql


REQUEST_ARGS = cgi.FieldStorage()
METRICS_FORMATTERS = {
    "HumidityLog": lambda x: x,
    "BmpTempLog": lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32,
    "PressureLog": lambda p: p * 0.0002953,
    "AltitudeLog": lambda m: m * 3.28084,
    "TemperatureLog": lambda c: c * 1.8 + 32,
    "SeaPressureLog": lambda p: p * 0.0002953,
}


def connect_to_database():
    return pymysql.connect(
        db='WeatherLog',
        user='WeatherLog',
        passwd='Weather!',
        host='localhost')


def select_from_database(cursor, table, start_date, end_date, minute_grouping):
    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT Logged, Avg(Value)
        FROM %s
        WHERE Logged >= '%s' AND Logged <= '%s'
        GROUP BY ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Logged)/(%s * 60));
    """, (table, start_date, end_date, minute_grouping))
    return cursor.fetchall()


def date_from_now(days_limit, fmt):
    earlier = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=days_limit)
    return earlier.strftime(fmt)


def retrieve_start_and_end_date(days_limit=7, fmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"):
    date_start = REQUEST_ARGS.getvalue('Start') if 'Start' in REQUEST_ARGS else date_from_now(days_limit, fmt)
    end_date = REQUEST_ARGS.getvalue('End') if 'End' in REQUEST_ARGS else datetime.utcnow().strftime(fmt)
    return date_start, date_end


def send_response(content, headers=["Content-type: text/html"]):
    for header in headers:
        print header
    print
    for line in content:
        print line
```

**index.py**

```
import utils


def file_iterator(filename):
    with open(filename) as content:
        for line in content:
            yield line.rstrip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.send_response(file_iterator('index.html'))
```

**latest.py**

```
import utils


def metrics_fetcher():
    start_date, end_date = utils.retrieve_start_and_end_date()
    connection = utils.connect_to_database()
    with connection as cursor:
        for table, formatter in utils.METRICS_FORMATTER.iteritems():
            rows = utils.select_from_database(cursor, table, start_date, end_date, minute_grouping=1)
            for row in rows:
                yield '{}\t{}\t{}'.format(table[:-3], row[0], formatter(row[1]))
    connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.send_response(metrics_fetcher())
```

**history.py**

```
import utils


def history_fetcher(default_table):
    table = utils.REQUEST_ARGS.getvalue('LogType') + 'Log' if 'LogType' in utils.REQUEST_ARGS else default_table
    try:
        formatter = utils.METRICS_FORMATTER[table]
    except KeyError:
        table = default_table
        formatter = utils.METRICS_FORMATTER[table]

    start_date, end_date = utils.retrieve_start_and_end_date()
    connection = utils.connect_to_database()
    with connection as cursor:
        rows = utils.select_from_database(cursor, table, start_date, end_date, minute_grouping=3)
        yield 'Logged\tValue'
        for row in rows:
            yield '{}\t{}'.format(row[0], formatter(row[1]))
    connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    utils.send_response(history_fetcher(default_table='TemperatureLog'))
```